# Apply aggregate function before taking where criteria

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, TABLE_A and TABLE_B. This is what I want to do: Take all unique occurrences of FIELD_2 in TABLE_A, together with the highest occurring FIELD_1 for each of them. Then, select only those of FIELD_1 which I have there, where the corresponding FIELD_3 in TABLE_B is not 'OK'. (FIELD_1 exists in both TABLE_A and TABLE_B.)

At first I started with a straightforward approach where I did this in three steps, just as described above. (To see what I did it is easiest to begin with Step 1, and work your way outwards, that is how I wrote the code):

```
/* START Step 3 – Take only those of the highest FIELD_1 from TABLE_A, where the corresponding FIELD_3 in TABLE_B is not ‘OK’ */
SELECT DISTINCT
    FIELD_1
FROM
    TABLE_B
WHERE
    FIELD_1 IN 
    (
    /* START Step 2 – Take only the highest FIELD_1 from Step 1 */
    SELECT
        MAXFIELD_1
    FROM
        (
        /* START Step 1 – Take the highest FIELD_1 for all of the FIELD_2 which are in TABLE_A */
        SELECT
            FIELD_2, 
            MAX(FIELD_1) MAXFIELD_1
        FROM
            TABLE_A 
        GROUP BY
            FIELD_2
        /* END Step 1 */
        )
    /* END Step 2 */
    )
AND
    FIELD_3 <> 'OK'
/* END Step 3 */
```

However, as I continue with what I want to do this gets uglier and uglier, and I am looking for a way to shorten it by using JOIN statement. At first I tried this:

```
SELECT
    A.FIELD_2, 
    MAX(A.FIELD_1) FIELD_1 
FROM
    TABLE_A A
    INNER JOIN TABLE_B B ON A.FIELD_1 = B.FIELD_1
WHERE 
    B.FIELD_3 <> 'OK'
GROUP BY
    A.FIELD_2
```

Unfortunately, what now seems to happen is that MAX(A.FIELD_1) returns the highest FIELD_1 in TABLE_A where the corresponding FIELD_3 <> 'OK'. In other words, the where statement is applied first, *then* the highest FIELD_1 is selected. I would need to first select A.FIELD_2 and MAX(A.FIELD_1), and *after that*, take only those occurrences where B.FIELD_3 <> 'OK'.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand where you applied your first requirement:

> Take all unique occurrences of FIELD_2 in TABLE_A

I was expecting to see a `DISTINCT` keyword in your query.

Nevertheless, if you want to filter `B.FIELD_3 <> 'OK'` after taking the fields `A.FIELD_2` and `MAX(A.FIELD_1)`, you can use the `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT
    A.FIELD_2, 
    MAX(A.FIELD_1) FIELD_1,
    B.FIELD_3,
FROM
    TABLE_A A
    INNER JOIN TABLE_B B ON A.FIELD_1 = B.FIELD_1
GROUP BY
    A.FIELD_2
HAVING
    FIELD_3 <> 'OK'
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it did not seem to work. I made one correction to be able to run it, which was that I added B.FIELD_3 in the GROUP BY. The result is exactly the same records as in my previous try.

I think the problem might have to do with the fact that I include B:FIELD_3 in the beginning. That is, at first, in the SELECT term, I get the highest A.FIELD_1 for each occurrence of B.FIELD_3. So then I end up getting a record both for the highest A.FIELD_1 where B.FIELD_3 is 'OK', and also one with the highest A.FIELD_1 for all other B.FIELD_3.

Comment: Then afterwards, when I include the HAVING term, I end up selecting only the highest B:FIELD_3 where A.FIELD_1 was not 'OK', which was what I tried to avoid. 

I also tried to run it without B.FIELD_3 in the SELECT term in the beginning, but it still did not work.

Comment: By the way, you said in the beginning that you expected a DISTINCT in the query. I thought I did not need to use DISTINCT when I was using GROUP BY, but maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: I guess we need to see your database design. Please show us the schema of your tables A and B, and how they are related with each other.

Comment: I am sorry, I am not sure how to answer that, but I will try. TABLE_A and TABLE_B are both enormous with a lot of fields which are not relevant here. They both have the fields FIELD_1 and FIELD_2, whereas only TABLE_B has the FIELD_3. Moreover, any record contained in TABLE_A is also contained in TABLE_B, with the same FIELD_1 and FIELD_2. But there are many records in TABLE_B which are not included in TABLE_A. The only reason I need to use TABLE_B at all, is to be able to select only records from TABLE_A where the corresponding FIELD_3 <> 'OK'. 

Did this in any way answer your question? :)